# How to stop background runnning app on button action

Tags: ios

I want to stop a background running app on a button action, and also start a process on button click through code. Is it is possible?

Comment: where have you put those two buttons ?

Comment: And what do you mean by "stop process" ? Do you care of the app being rejected ?

Comment: It's entirely a function of what "background" process you want to stop on the press of one button (e.g. `NSOperationQueue`? `NSURLConnection`?) and what what process you wish to initiate on the press of another. This question will undoubtedly be down-voted or closed if you don't clarify. Help us help you.

Comment: i want to stop background location updation when i click wait buttton both function on same class and after when click another button on same  class it start updating location again

Comment: You want to enable/disable background execution from the same aoo at foreground ? What's exactly the problem then ?

Comment: yes i want to disable and enable location update in background because if user press  button and want to disable location updation for sometime ..

Comment: @widevision - Just have your `IBAction` call the `stopUpdatingLocation` method (or whatever) of the location manager object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. In application delegate background method.